# Am I using the LINQ .OfType() operator correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
public class Stock
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        cache["test"] = new Stock();
        var x = cache.OfType<Stock>().ToList();
    }
}
```

This is returning empty ...I thought OfType is supposed to return all instances in a collection of type T ?

Just to rule out the ObjectCache as a possible culprit I also tried

```
List<object> lstTest = new List<object>();
        lstTest.Add(new Stock());
        var y = lstTest.OfType<Stock>().ToList();
```

This works however - so it seems like the problem is with the ObjectCache, which is an instance of a Dictionary underneath

**SOLUTION**

```
cache.Select(item => item.Value).OfType<T>().ToList()
```

Thanks Alexei!

Comment: Your second sample still uses `cache`: `y = cache.OfType<Stock>()...` Should work fine.

Comment: Ooops missed that ..that works, however, I wonder why it doesn't work for the ObjectCache which is really a Dictionary underneath ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MemoryChache returns enumerator of `KeyValuePair<string,Object>`, not just values: [MemoryChache.GetEnumerator()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getenumerator).

You need to case accordingly to get your items. Something like:

```
var y = cache.Select(item => item.Value).OfType<Stock>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was ready to rip my hair out. THANK YOU!

Comment: +1: @AlexeiLevenkov I'd say your way is better than mine:):):)!! I didn't catch at once that it was possible to get values the way you did..

Answer (score 2):

This would work

```
cache.GetValues(new string[] {"test"}).Values.OfType<Order>()
```

But I don't think you should use this.
Cache works like a Dictionary...so you can get set of `KeyValuePairs` with `GetValues`

Comment: I guess, positive side of `GetValues` is that it gives an opportunity to provide a list of keys to search

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Sorry myself. ObjectCache is a IEnumerable>
Not really an IDictionary.

This works:

```
var c = cache.Select(o => o.Value).OfType<Stock>().ToList();
```

Comment: Yes. I just update the answer. You have to get the collection of values first. ObjectCache is IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

public class Stock
    {
        public Stock()
        {
            Name = "Erin";
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Collections.ArrayList fruits = new System.Collections.ArrayList(4);
        fruits.Add("Mango");
        fruits.Add("Orange");
        fruits.Add("Apple");
        fruits.Add(3.0);
        fruits.Add("Banana");
        fruits.Add(new Stock());

        // Apply OfType() to the ArrayList.
        var query1 = fruits.OfType<Stock>();

        Console.WriteLine("Elements of type 'stock' are:");
        foreach (var fruit in query1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fruit);
        }

    }
}
```

Remember IEnumerable is lazily evaluated.  Use a foreach to loop through query1 and you will see it only find the Stock object.